# Get parameters out of a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

is there a simple methode to check 2 strings if they contains the same parameter?

Example:

- ReferenceString = "something {0} {1} {2:X}"
- String2 = "something else {0} {1} {2:X}"
- String3 = "something else {0} {0} {2:X}"
- String4 = "something else {0} {1} {2}"
- String5 = "something else {0} {1}"

So what I need is to check is:

1. That all strings contains the same amount of parameters example
   String5 is missing {2:X}
2. That the typo of the parameter is also correct like String3 has
   two time {0}{0} instead {0}{1}
3. The Format is also the same example String4 last parameter is not
   correct.

I don't need to specify what is wrong, just a general check like return true if same or return false if wrong

What I do is convert the string to an CharaArray then going through all chara etc.. which is I think not the best solution

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Can you use `string.Contains()`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract all parameters with regex `{(?<parameter>.+?)}`. It will match opening brace `{` and then any number of characters (as small as possible) before match closing brace `}`.

After this you can group all parameters found and if there is only one group that means that parameters are same. To group by a collection of strings you need to define custom equality comparer:

```
public class CustomEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.Count == y.Count && 
          x.Select((s, i) => (s: s, i: i)).All(t => t.s.Equals(y[t.i]));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
    {
        return obj.Aggregate(293, (c, n) => c ^ n.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var input = new[]
{
    "something {0} {1} {2:X}",
    "something else {0} {1} {2:X}",
    "something else {0} {0} {2:X}",
    "something else {0} {1} {2}",
    "something else {0} {1}",
};

var regex = new Regex("{(?<parameter>.+?)}");

var parameters = input
    .Select(i => 
        regex.Matches(i)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Groups["parameter"].Value)
            .ToList()
        )
    .GroupBy(x => x, new CustomEqualityComparer());

var areSame = parameters.Count() == 1;
```

If you define your input as

```
var input = new[]
{
    "a {0} b {1} c",
    "{0} {1}",
};
```

`areSame` will be true

---

**Edit**:

If your input strings are taken from a first argument of `string.Format` or `Console.Write` then (as **canton7** said in comment) they can contains escapes like `{{not a parametr}}`. If this is your case you need to modify regular expression to

```
(?<!{){(?!{)(?<parametr>.+?)}
```

Explanation:

```
(?<!{)          // check that there is no { char before
{               // match { literally 
(?!{)           // check that there is no { char after
  (             // start capturing group
    ?<parametr> // this capturing group name is "parametr"
    .+?         // match any char (except a new line) as few times as possible
  )             // end of capturing group
}               // match } literally
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NYp8A9/1)

Note that this regex may match invalid groups (line 4 in demo) that in real code will throw `FormatException`. I hope that this is not your case.

Also in case your input is formed from string interpolation like

```
$"difficult { string.Concat(new[] { 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g' }) }"
```

I'm not aware of easy way to achieve what you want

Comment: Don't forget that `{{` and `}}` are escapes

Comment: Thaaaaaaank You

Comment: can you kindly help me with `return x.Count == y.Count && 
          x.Select((s, i) => (s: s, i: i)).All(t => t.s.Equals(y[t.i]));` at home I had to install the system.ValueTuple as my target Frame is .NT 4.6... here in the office I cannot install that package I get the error that `All` `S` `i` are not recognized and other syntax Error

Comment: @NizarBelhiba you can use an anonymous object instead of tuples. Replace `(s: s, i: i)` with `new {s, i}`